# d3 geojson works in v2, but not in v4

Tags: d3.js

I'm following http://bl.ocks.org/minikomi/4043986 on building a geojson d3 graph. But somehow the graph is not working when v2 changed to v4.

What's the reason behind this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer d3 v4 API.
d3.geo().albers() works with d3 v3. In v4 you might have to use d3.geoAlbers() instead.
Similarly for d3.geo.path() you might have to use d3.geoPath()
This might help you https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#geographies-d3-geo